# Identify data of particular fields from a PDF or a string containing a paragraph

Tags: python, java, android, pdf

I'm developing an Android app in which I want to Extract Text from the PDF,
Identify the data from the extracted text, and Store it in the database.

For example:

> If I have a HealthReport.pdf in which all health checkup results are written.
> I want to identify the data of some particular fields, for example: age, gender, weight, height, blood group, etc.
> And store it in the database.

Now I'm able to extract text from the PDF.
But **I don't know how to identify data from it** that this is weight, this is gender, this is height, this is weight, etc.

If anyone has some idea, plz help...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is way too large for stackoverflow, which is about specific problems in your code. Your question looks like you want us to write the code for you, which tends to lead to downvotes, and even if that's not the case, it involves pdf extraction, finding the text, and database access. Each could be their own question. Please see [ask].

Comment: @Robert I don't want someone to write the whole code, I just want the idea for code to identify data of some particular fields from the extracted text. I have done the extraction & database part. Just getting trouble in "how to detect the fields". If now also you feel that my question is wrong, "Sorry, I'm am a beginner in coding & stackoverflow".

Comment: An example of the extracted text would be useful. Also, any information on how consistent is the extracted text, i.e. are the only differences between different PDF files in the parameter values or are the PDF files and extracted text very different.

Answer (score -1):

I belive that this is somenthing you are looking for: https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/

Use OCR for character recognition and extraction, and than export that data into some sort of a .csv file so that it would be easier to organize.

Comment: The OP wrote that the actual extraction of the data (aka OCR) is solved, but the attribution of the data (which characters mean what) not - how does your answer help to solve this?